# SharePoint Framework Webpart Dependency Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I have created a RSSFeed Webpart from Scratch its working fine on https://savan.sharepoint.com/sites/365AppzDev/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx" but when i deployed its sppkg file to appcatalog and added it to webpart page its giving me the following error.
How to reslove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the steps that you can try to get it working

1. Upload the files found in the "webpartfolder\temp\deploy" to a sharepoint document library
2. Update the cdnBasePath property (found in the file write-manifests.json) with the path to library where you have uploaded your files.  This write-manifests.json file is located in the config folder
3. Rebundle your webpart and upload the new package to the app catalogue

Answer (score 1):

The resource files should be deployed in cdn or SharePoint library.
The below link will give you steps to deploy in CDN.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDGatKnjNeM

To use the SharePoint for your resource files you can follow below steps.

1. Update the SharePoint library path in the <>/config/write-manifest.json -> cdnBasePath
2. Run the "gulp bundle --ship" command, It will generate new resource files under "<>/temp/deploy" folder. Copy to SharePoint library path you specified.
3. Run "gulp Package-solution" to get new .sppkg file. Deploy the new file.
4. Follow steps to add to page. It should work.

Thanks,
Venkat Konjeti

Answer (score 0):

The .sppkg does not contain any js, css, images etc. These need to be deployed to a cdn (or similar ).

Source: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/deploy-web-part-to-cdn

You can enable a CDN on your tenant, if it is provisioned.

Source: https://dev.office.com/blogs/office-365-public-cdn-developer-preview-release